# latex pgf / tikz array / loop over a pgf key in combination with nicematrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, nicematrix

I'm trying to achieve that, in the text (here inside the nicematrix env) I can add elements to a pgf key (maybe something like an array or simple extending a string) and later on I'd like to iterate over these.

What I've got so far (not working :/ )

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{/try1/.code={\def\addArray{#1}}}
\begin{align*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \pgfkeys{/try1={1-3/2-3/2}}
        \draw (0,0) node {\try1};
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in {\try1}
            \draw (mymatrix-\x) ++(.75em,0) -- ++(.75em,0) node [anchor=west]{\tiny \z} |- ($ (mymatrix-\y) + (0.75em,0) $);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I already tried to set the value directly via `/try1/.initial={...}` and adding via `/try1/.add={...}{}` but nothing worked so far.

I definitely need help, since I'm not too familiar with pgfkeys and nothing I found while searching worked.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: For @schroedingers cat question:
The goal is something like this (but with a new environment):

```
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\ \add[2]{1}
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
```

It should be something to write gaussian eliminations. My idea was that I'd collect all add/swap/mult commands by converting them to tikz commands and execute them in the end after closing the `bNiceMatrix`  environment.

The reason, why I want to collect them rather than just specify all conversions in one command, is that this way I can access an internal counter/macro of nicematrix to get the current row number (at least I should be able to). A problem I'll have to solve is also that for some reason I cannot access the tikz nodes created by `pNiceMatrix`  when being still inside the same `align` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key forwards its argument to the `\addArray` macro, but you are using the `\try1` macro, which does not exist. So to first approximation you could just use `\addArray` instead.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{/try1/.code={\def\addArray{#1}}}
\begin{align*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \pgfkeys{/try1={1-3/2-3/2}}
        %\draw (0,0) node {\addArray};
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in \addArray
            \draw (mymatrix-\x) ++(.75em,0) -- ++(.75em,0) node [anchor=west]{\tiny \z} |- ($ (mymatrix-\y) + (0.75em,0) $);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, it might make sense to make this more versatile. You can just add a key for the code, and use the `/.list` key handler to get the loop.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{add annotation/.code={%
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in {#1}
            \draw ([xshift=1ex]\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/atticus/matrix name}-\x.east) 
             -- ++(.75em,0) node
            [anchor=west,font=\tiny]{ \z} |- 
            ([xshift=1ex]\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/atticus/matrix name}-\y.east);
},atticus/.cd,matrix name/.initial=mymatrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \tikzset{add annotation/.list={1-3/2-3/2,2-3/3-3/a}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the hard coded `mymatrix` also got replaced by a pgf key, and the path has been modified to involve less hard coded values.

**ADDENDUM**: I think this should be a separate question as it deviates quite a bit from the original question. Yet here is a version that stacks the keys.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\let\mylist\relax
\pgfkeys{/try1/.code=\ifx\mylist\relax
\edef\mylist{#1}%
\else
\edef\mylist{\mylist,#1}%
\fi,/atticus/.cd,matrix name/.initial=mymatrix
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \pgfkeys{/try1={1-3/2-3/2}}
        \pgfkeys{/try1={2-3/3-3/3}}
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in \mylist
         {  
            \draw ([xshift=1ex]\pgfkeysvalueof{/atticus/matrix name}-\x.east) 
             -- ++(.75em,0) node
            [anchor=west,font=\tiny]{ \z} |- 
            ([xshift=1ex]\pgfkeysvalueof{/atticus/matrix name}-\y.east);
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For further requests please consider asking a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. Since I want to dynamically add elements throughout the matrix, I think I'll stick with the first one, with something like this, `\pgfkeys{/try1={\addArray, newSet}}` it should be possible to add other values right?

Comment: @atticus I would be surprised if that worked. You can use `/.append code` to append code, but not in the way you are setting things up here. To give you an advice that will help you most I probably need some more information on how all this is going to be used.

Comment: I've added what I want to achieve and what I thought how I might be able to achieve it. But as I'm not that experienced in LaTeX coding (and environment coding) I feel a bit lost, so any help is apprecheated

Comment: @atticus I added something of that sort but would kindly ask you to start a new question for more follow-up questions.

Comment: Already thought, that it doesn't really fit into this question. The big problem remaining is that somehow I have to end the `align` env to access the generated tiktz nodes. But  for that one I'll make a new question ;)

Comment: I have one question left regarding the placement of the `\pgfkeys{/try1={2-3/3-3/3}}` command, but I'll have to wait to be able to ask it.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548018/latex-tikz-pgfkeys